# How can I tell that an excel file is write reserved before opening it?

Tags: excel

I have a program that opens excel files, performs functions on them, and then saves them, all without user interaction. I've come across some files that are "write reserved". This is different from password protection, but still require a password to access.

I'd like to tell if these files are write reserved before opening them so I can avoid a prompt, but in order to access the Workbook.WriteReserved property, I must open the file. I'd like to resolve this catch-22 somehow... but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Comment: Would `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before opening and testing `Workbook.WriteReserved` do the trick?

Comment: Application.DisplayAlerts = False did not suppress the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround that I found was to supply a bogus password for the write reservation when opening the workbook. Files that are not write reserved (99% of my use cases) pass unhindered, while the rest that are will throw an exception which I can handle. Not clean, but it works.